Show media notification via audio service in flutter
I'm using just_audio package for playing music in my app.
I want to display media notification while playing audio that has next, previous,resume,pause and stop buttons.
I've added audio_service package to my project and configured it as shown below:
late AudioHandler audioHandler;

void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  audioHandler = await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => MyAudioHandler(),
    config: AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.mycompany.myapp.channel.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Music playback',

    ),
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}


class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler with QueueHandler, SeekHandler {

  Future<void> play() => musicPlayer.play();
  Future<void> pause() => musicPlayer.pause();
  Future<void> stop() => musicPlayer.stop();
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) => musicPlayer.seek(position);
  Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int i) => musicPlayer.seek(Duration.zero, index: i);
}

I play music using just_audio with musicPlayer and run this code after the music starts playing:
 await musicPlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(path)));

          var item = MediaItem(
            id: path,
            album: 'Album name',
            title: 'Track title',
            artist: 'Artist name',
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 123456),
            artUri: Uri.parse('https://example.com/album.jpg'),
          );

          audioHandler.playMediaItem(item);


But the notification isn't shown.
note: android manifest has been configured as instructed in the audio_service docs.
note: notification permission is granted.
